# How can we update the comments while reassigning the approval request

Tags: apex

How can we update the comments while reassigning the approval request.

Could you please suggest.

Fyi,I would be able to update actorId using ProcessInstanceWorkItem but not comment.

If you have any alternatives if you suggest that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign an approval request by updating the actorId on the ProcessInstanceWorkItem, however you cannot add/update comments. Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfNnUAJ/processworkitemrequest-reassign-with-apex).

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Is there any way we can achieve reassigning of non admin or submitter.

Comment: You can use flow and re-assign pending requests to a user/ queue, check [example](https://automationchampion.com/2021/01/01/getting-started-with-salesforce-flow-part-49-reassign-pending-approval-requests/).